# flex soap 1.2 webservice

Tags: apache-flex, soap

I want to connect to a soap 1.2 web service. I know how to do it with a soap 1.1 connection. But it doesn't work for a soap 1.2.
Can anyone tell me if there is a workaround for my problem?
With kind regard, JSMB

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Flex/AS3 supports SOAP 1.2. See [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html):

> The Flex web service API generally supports Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) 1.1, XML Schema 1.0 (versions 1999, 2000, and 2001), and WSDL 1.1 RPC-encoded, RPC-literal, and document-literal (bare and wrapped style parameters). The two most common types of web services use remote procedure call (RPC) encoded or document-literal SOAP bindings; the terms encoded and literal indicate the type of WSDL-to-SOAP mapping that a service uses.

You can create your own wrapper using over the [`AbstractWebService`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/soap/AbstractWebService.html) class or use a similar class (like `HTTPRequest`) to do the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have a working version now, I used a webserver from a person called alducente
http://alducente.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/web-service-in-as3-release-10/